# Why do we use low-pass filter to eliminate the gravity effect on the accelerator?

Tags: android, accelerator

I am trying to do something with the accelerator, i am reading the documentation and it gives the general formula as follows

```
Ad = -g - ∑F / mass
```

so i thought we will simply just subtract the gravity value from the result to get the acceleration, but in the documentation it says that we need to use a low-pass filter as follows

```
 final float alpha = 0.8;

      gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
      gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
      gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

      linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
      linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
      linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
```

if any body can explain to me why i'll be thankful

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to just subtract the gravity if you know it. There are two reasons why this might be difficult, however. First, the gravity is a vector and the current direction is likely unknown without measuring it. Second, the exact magnitude of the gravity varies by location (and inaccuracies in the sensor).

What the low pass filter does is to estimate the gravity vector for you, since this is almost constant whereas other accelerations are assumed to be temporary. Sudden rotations or constant acceleration that lasts for long could affect the accuracy of this estimate.

To improve the estimate of the gravity, you could try to estimate the direction only and adjust its size or try to combine data from for example a gyro to take rotation into consideration also.

Comment: I feel like the question i am going to ask is a third grade student question :D, but excuse me how come the gravity vector direction is unknown :/, shouldn't it point always toward y-axis?

Comment: I think that could be the case if there's some way to guarantee that the physical sensor is always oriented with that axis towards the gravity (not impossible!). However, if the sensor is fixed inside for example a smartphone, there's no way to keep the end user from pointing it in any direction and then the direction of "down" needs to be dynamically measured.

Comment: Put another way, the sensor and the "world" have their own coordinate systems and it could be that they don't align, especially if the sensor can be rotated around freely.

Comment: Ah, i got it, but i read that, the physical sensor actually contains something like a ball "test particle" which i think what determines the gravity :/, but i amn't sure anyway so thanks alot, you made it clear for me